# creating individuals with same name in protege

Tags: ontology, protege

I am using Protege 5.2 to create domain specific ontology and i need to create two individuals with the same name under the same class, is there away to do that in protege.

Comment: Do you mean same IRI? If so, that's not possible in OWL. Same IRI means same object.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Wouldn't they be the same individual?

Comment: I have Pneumonic disease Diagnosed_by Oxygen_saturation that it's  description is low blood oxygen under 88%. and Pulmonary embolism disease Diagnosed_by Oxygen_saturation that  it's description is low blood oxygen under 90%. so,i think i need to create two individuals of Investigation class which is Low blood oxygen is that right and what is the solution  if it is not ? @TobiasGeiselmann

Comment: Where are the percentage values described? Or are they modelled as axioms in your ontology? I would simply make Oxygen_saturation a class (as you probably did) and give that class a value between 0 and 1 (modelled as a data property).

Answer (score 0):

You may do this if you develop your ontology following the OWL2 specification (this is not allowed with OWL1) by first creating a new individual (for instance in the individuals tab) and modifying a posteriori its iri (ctrl+u on most platforms).

Note that the new entity will be completely independent from the original class, including for reasoning. See more details on the W3c page about "punning"[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-new-features-20121211/#F12:_Punning)